# Using unittest & mock to test a UUT with urlopen

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm struggling to resolve the name space issues while testing code that calls URL's with urlopen.
I've tried to mock the function with some success but I want to achieve 2 things which I don't seem to be able to do concurrently:

1. Use a *mocked* object to test how the UUT responds to raised exceptions and various return codes.
2. Use the useful functions such as *call_count* and *call_args* to check what was done to the URL inside the UUT (the full code has more functionality).

I've tried everything I can think of but as it stands the simplified code looks like this:

**test_a_mock.py**

```py
from uut import Call_URL
import unittest
import unittest.mock as mock
from MockTypes import Urlopen

class Test_webhook(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_webhook(self):
        with mock.patch('urllib.request.urlopen', new=Urlopen) as mock_urlopen:
            Call_URL("http://10.0.10.180:3001/api/push/fFWFJscQXd?status=up&msg=OK&ping=")
            print("call_count: {}".format(mock_urlopen.call_count))
            print("called_once: {}".format(mock_urlopen.called_once()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()  # pragma: no cover
```

**uut.py**

```py
import json
import urllib
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
from http import HTTPStatus

def Call_URL(URL):
    try:

        Response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)
        HTTP_Code = Response.getcode()
        if HTTP_Code != HTTPStatus.OK:
            print("WebHook {} returned {}: {}".format(
                                            URL, HTTP_Code, HTTPStatus(HTTP_Code).name))
        Page_JSON = json.loads(Response.read())
        print("Page_JSON: {}".format(Page_JSON))
        if "ok" in Page_JSON:
            if Page_JSON["ok"] is not True:
                if "msg" in Page_JSON:
                    Message = Page_JSON["msg"]
                else:
                    Message = "none"
                print(
                    "The webhook returned an 'ok' element as not True with the message '{}'".format(
                        Message))
    except HTTPError as Error:
        if hasattr(Error, 'reason'):
            print("Failed to call webhook. Reason: {}".format(Error.reason))
        if hasattr(Error, 'code'):
            print("Webhook server couldn't fulfill request. Error: {}".format(
                Error.code))
        return
    except URLError as Error:
        if hasattr(Error, 'reason'):
            print("Failed to call webhook. Reason: {}".format(Error.reason))
        return
    return
```

**MockType.py**

```py
import unittest.mock as mock
from http import HTTPStatus

class Urlopen(mock.Mock):
    def __init__(self, url, **kwargs):
        mock.Mock.__init__(self)
        self._url = url
        self._response = []
        self.code = HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST
        pass

    def getcode(self):
        return self.code

    def geturl(self):
        return self._url

    def read(self):
        return '{"ok": "Mock data"}'
```

I'm assuming I've misunderstood how to achieve what I'm aiming for so any advice would be welcomed.

Comment: `Call_URL` does far more than simply retrieve data from a URL. It should be split into two functions, one that makes the request and one that processes the data. The latter can be easily tested by passing it arbitrary JSON code. The first one would still need to patch `urllib.request.urlopen`, but would otherwise be trivial to test, as all it really needs to do is *produce* JSON, not process it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

To give a solution, the issue was my misunderstanding of the right structure to use:

1. When you patch a function, let mock create the mock function and do not try to create from a new object using the new=A_Class
2. To test 'normal' functional flow, define a class that will become the returned object by calls to your mocked function. This should have attributes and function calls suited to your tests (see below). This is shown below as the `.return_value` line.
3. To test 'abnormal' flows such as exceptions use the `.side_effect` function of the mocked call to return an error object such as HTTPError

```py
BASE_CONFIG = {
    "WEBHOOKS": {},
    }

class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app = flask.Flask(__name__)
        app.config.update(BASE_CONFIG)
        self.app = app
        Add_Logging_Levels()
        app.logger.setLevel("DEBUG")

@mock.patch("urllib.request.urlopen", autospec=True)
class Test_webhook_call_url(BaseTestCase):
    # HTTP Error
    def test_webhook_http_error(self, mock_urlopen):
        url = "http://xxxxx"
        rtn_obj = Urlopen(url)
        mock_urlopen.return_value = rtn_obj
        mock_urlopen.side_effect = HTTPError(url=url, code=HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST, msg="Bad request", hdrs=None, fp=None)

        with self.assertLogs('tests', level='DEBUG') as cm:
            Rtn = Call_URL(self.app, url)
            self.assertEqual(cm.output, [
                "WARNING:tests.unit.test_webhook:Failed to call webhook. Reason: Bad request",
                "WARNING:tests.unit.test_webhook:Webhook server couldn't "
                "fulfill request Error: 400",
                ])

        self.assertFalse(Rtn)

    # Normal
    def test_webhook_normal(self, mock_urlopen):
        url = "http://xxxxxxxx"
        rtn_obj = Urlopen(url)
        mock_urlopen.return_value = rtn_obj
        Rtn = Call_URL(self.app, url)
        self.assertTrue(Rtn)
        self.assertEqual(mock_urlopen.call_count, 1)
        self.assertEqual(rtn_obj.geturl(), url)
```

You object can be:

```py
import unittest.mock as mock
from http import HTTPStatus

class Urlopen(mock.MagicMock):
    def __init__(self, url, code=HTTPStatus.OK, read_data='{"ok":true}', **kwargs):
        mock.MagicMock.__init__(self)
        self._url = url
        self._code = code
        self._read_data = read_data
        pass

    def getcode(self):
        return self._code

    def geturl(self):
        return self._url

    def read(self):
        return self._read_data
```

You can build on this to check how your functions construct, or change the URL according to your application needs.
Please note the extra code comes from the fact I'm unit testing in a flask app environment.